# Changing arrays to pointers and creating them on shared memory

Tags: c++, c, sockets

I got a struct which contains multiple array members. Size of the array member is not static but it will be dynamic which shall be determined at runtime

struct was declared like this

```
typedef struct
{
  typea mem[MAXLEN];
  typeb mem1[MAXLEN]
  typec no[MAXLEN + 1]
  int code
}T;
```

but now MAXLEN is not a constant and size of arrays will be determined at runtime so I changed the declaration to

```
typedef struct
{
  typea *mem;
  typeb *mem1;
  typec *no;
  int code
}T;
```

Problem is this struct is shared with other processes using shared memory and also sent over socket so by changing array to pointer struct members are not continuous so I can't send them in single msgsend. No need to send MAXLEN as it is also present on client side only content must be sent over socket and also shared using mmap call. How to do this with minimum changes?
Thanks

Comment: You need to pack your structure. There is no guarantee that the structure has the same memory layout on the client side (this is machine/compiler dependent). The compiler is free to reorder/pad this structure. (See `#pragma pack`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can allocate the structure and all it's data as one large chunk of memory, and just make the pointers point to the correct offset. Then it's easy to "send" all data at once.

Something like

```
size_t size = sizeof(T) + sizeof(typea) * MAXLEN + sizeof(typeb) * MAXLEN + sizeof(typec) * (MAXLEN + 1);
char *base = malloc(size);

T *t = (T *) base;
t->mem  = (typea *) (base + sizeof(T));
t->mem1 = (typeb *) (base + sizeof(T) + sizeof(typea) * MAXLEN);
t->no   = (typec *) (base + sizeof(T) + sizeof(typea) * MAXLEN + sizeof(typeb) * MAXLEN);
```

When sending over socket, the receiving size knows `MAXLEN` and so knows how much it should receive. Then it it does the same with the allocation and the member assignment, and can in theory do a single receive call to receive all data.

Comment: Your solution will work but I am actually searching for a solution which will keep all struct members continous assuming no padding as it would be easy to create and read such structures using mmap. I tried using flexible array but it seems that one structure can have only one flexible array member and multiple flexible array members shares same memory location.

Comment: @user3494614 Well, all data *will* be continuous, just not inside the structure itself. As you discovered yourself, you can't have multiple flexible arrays in a structure, so if you want continuous data this is basically the only way to handle it. It will of course work with `mmap` too, just use the correct `mmap` call instead of `malloc`.